# FTDI RS485 to USB adapter trying to read port as binary using Rasp PI and Python

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port

I'm new to python and am having trouble figuring out how to read a serial port out as Hex or binary. I have a FTDI RS485 to USB device that shows up as a virtual serial port on USB0. I found enough information to make the below code that reads out the serial data but it's showing up as characters and symbols and I haven't figured out how to output it as hex or binary instead so I can read the data.

```
import serial, sys
port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baudrate = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(port,baudrate,timeout=0.01)
while True
 data = ser.read(1)
 data+= ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
 sys.stdout.write(data)
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

As a full project overview, this is the first part of a larger goal to setup my raspPi to act as a datalogger on a RS485 network. I have a few RS485 devices networked that I believe are randomly missing messages but they don't have datalogging built in to confirm what is actually happening so my goal is to make one I can setup and leave for a week.

Comment: *"I have a FTDI RS485 to USB device ..."* -- Peripherals are typically described from the computer's perspective (rather than the user's).  Since the immediate connector is using the computer's USB port, the USB aspect should be mentioned *first*, and then the interface that is converted and exposed.  So it is a USB-to-RS485 converter.  *"how to read a serial port out as Hex or binary"* -- At the hardware level it is all simply data.  *"Characters and symbols"* are merely interpretations of specific binary values, or codes (or mappings) such as ASCII.

Comment: *"how to output it as hex or binary"* -- Then display/print the data as numbers rather than text.